# Trouble passing context in dialog

Tags: android

My current project uses a LOT of dialog boxes. For instance, I have a "Group" activity which lists users. Clicking a user will bring up a dialog showing their details(in this case history). It defaults showing the last 5 places visited, with an option to see a full history, which brings up a third dialog box and also where the trouble starts. I'm using volley and JSON to get the listarray, but I'm having trouble getting the context to pass in.

```
public class HistoryQView extends Dialog implements 
    android.view.View.OnClickListener, OnItemClickListener{

public Activity c;
public Dialog d;
public JSONHistory results;
public ListView members;


public HistoryQView(Activity a, String viewed) {
    super(a);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.c = a;
    this.viewed = viewed;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_qview);

    //blah, blah........
    getData();
}
public void getData() {
//blah, blah.......
RequestQueue queue = VolleySingleton.getInstance(getContext()).getRequestQueue();
JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
    Request.Method.GET, full_url, null,
    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() 
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        String example = response.toString();
        System.out.println(example);

        try {
            Gson googleJson = new Gson();
            JSONHistory rh = googleJson.fromJson(example,JSONHistory.class);
            for (JSONHistory e : rh.getJSONHistory()) {
                eventlist.add(e);
            }

            final ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.qviewListView);
            final HistoryAdapter adapter = new HistoryAdapter(HistoryQView.this, R.layout.list_history, eventlist);
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,final View view, int position, long id) {
                final JSONHistory thisevent = (JSONHistory) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                final String thiseid = thisevent.getEventInfo("eid");
                System.out.println(thiseid);

                //eventlist.remove(item);
                //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
});
queue.add(jsObjRequest);
```

}

I'm 99% sure the problem is that the context isn't passing to HistoryAdapter(probably because I'm not getting it correctly). I'm just really not sure how to fix this.

```
class HistoryAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<JSONHistory> {
private ArrayList<JSONHistory> items;

public HistoryAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
        ArrayList<JSONHistory> items) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
    System.out.println(context);
    this.items = items;
}
```

I've tried passing HistoryQView.this, HistoryQView.this.getActivity(), HistoryQView.this.getOwnerActivity()(this eliminates the compiler error, but passes NULL). I'm pretty much learning this as I go, and I'm out of ideas on how to fix and was hoping someone could help out. I appreciate it. I tried to cut out the code that doesn't apply, let me know if I got too carried away and you need to see something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's where you initialize your adapter:

```
        final HistoryAdapter adapter = new HistoryAdapter(HistoryQView.this, R.layout.list_history, eventlist);
```

That passes the dialog itself in as the first parameter, where you are expecting a Context. You cleverly store the Activity as a field in your constructor:

```
public HistoryQView(Activity a, String viewed) {
    super(a);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.c = a; // stores the activity!
    this.viewed = viewed;
}
```

So all you need to do is change that first line to use that field:

```
        final HistoryAdapter adapter = new HistoryAdapter(HistoryQView.this.c, R.layout.list_history, eventlist);
```